# tsyringe + LitElement dependency injection

Tags: lit, tsyringe

I have a `LitElement`-based web component to assist with advance forms validation. I would like to allow extensible validators to be added later via dependency injection.

In my testing the following code, `IValidate` classes registered before my web component is defined are available to the web component, but classes registered after the web component is defined are not:

```js
import { html, css, LitElement } from 'lit';
import { customElement, property } from 'lit/decorators.js';
import { container, injectable, InjectionToken } from 'tsyringe';

export interface IValidate {
    validate(input: HTMLElement): boolean;
}

export const ValidateToken: InjectionToken<IValidate> = 'ValidateToken';

@injectable()
export class ZipCodeValidator implements IValidate {
    validate(input: HTMLElement): boolean { return true; /* Implementation */ };
}
container.register(ValidateToken, { useClass: ZipCodeValidator });

@customElement('my-validate')
export class MyValidate extends LitElement {
    validators: IValidate[] = [];

    async connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        this.validators = container.resolveAll<IValidate>(ValidateToken);
        debugger; // this is hit first; this.validators.length == 1; I expected 2
    }
}

@injectable()
export class ExistsValidator implements IValidate {
    validate(input: HTMLElement): boolean { return true; /* Implementation */ };
}
debugger; // this is hit 2nd
container.register(ValidateToken, { useClass: ExistsValidator });
```

When I debug:

- The debugger breakpoint in `connectedCallback()` is hit before the 2nd debugger
- The ExistsValidator has not yet been registered.

I am surprised that the `connectedCallback` is being executed before we ever hit the `container.register(ValidateToken, { useClass: ExistsValidator });`

I create a distinct test that works as I would expect:

```js
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { container, injectable, InjectionToken } from 'tsyringe';
import { expect } from '@esm-bundle/chai';
export interface IFoo {
    validate(input: string): boolean;
}

export const FooToken: InjectionToken<IFoo> = 'FooToken';

@injectable()
export class FooA implements IFoo {
    validate(input: string): boolean { return input === "a" };
}
container.register(FooToken, { useClass: FooA });


@injectable()
export class FooB implements IFoo {
    validate(input: string): boolean { return input === "b" };
}
container.register(FooToken, { useClass: FooB });

describe('DI', () => {
    it('registers all validators', () => {
        const validators = container.resolveAll<IFoo>(FooToken);
        expect(validators.length).to.equal(4);
        console.log(validators.length);
    });
})

@injectable()
export class FooC implements IFoo {
    validate(input: string): boolean { return input === "c" };
}
container.register(FooToken, { useClass: FooC });

@injectable()
export class FooD implements IFoo {
    validate(input: string): boolean { return input === "d" };
}
container.register(FooToken, { useClass: FooD });
```

What am I missing? Is there a 'proper' way to mix DI (`tsyrige`) with `Lit`?